# cursor in nano bugs for longer lines

Tags: terminal, nano

When I am writing code in nano, the cursor bugs after some time. The cursor moves further to the right than the actual position. This makes it really difficult to debug when writing long lines.

By the way, I am using zsh on a mac, but I had the same problem with bash. It is also not specific for any programming language or file type, but happens always when I use nano.

Here are two images to illustrate the problem:

[image]

According to the cursor, hitting del should delete `d`, but it actually deletes `n`. However, when I go at the beginning of the line:

[image]

hitting del correctly deletes `u`.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Is the behaviour switching from correct to incorrect as you advance past the ä?

Comment: Yess!!! Can't believe I didn't notice this yet. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Why would the shell matter? When you're in `nano` you're not using the shell.

Comment: I'm just giving the information that I considered to be relevant. I'm no expert on the topic, else I probably would not ask this question.